# ServiceStack OrmLite: Table field type when create table form c#

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I need create table field when type "Text".

```
public class PropsTable {
   public string PropKey { get; set; }        
   public string PropValue { get; set; }
}
....

db.CreateTableIfNotExists<PropsTable>();
```

when I do this type: varchar(255)

you can then decide how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic (i.e. cross-RDBMS) way to tell OrmLite to create a table with a large text field is to use `[StringLength(StringLengthAttribute.MaxText)]`, e.g:

```
public class PropsTable 
{
   public string PropKey { get; set; }        

   [StringLength(StringLengthAttribute.MaxText)]
   public string PropValue { get; set; }
}
```

For RDBMS-specific column definitions you can use `[CustomField]`, e.g:

```
[CustomField("text")]
public string PropValue { get; set; }
```